# Getting content security policy error while hash is included

Tags: content-security-policy

I have a problem although i have included (as you can see) the hash for inline style="height:18px" (attribute) i still get csp error (pages are in ghostjs )

```
Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content 
Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com 
fonts.googleapis.com https://intercom.help/_assets 
'sha256-HKIQe1rxf7BKTQyeVymEQz4wG30GqXPn7nokufiyhRk='". 
Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
('sha256-HKIQe1rxf7BKTQyeVymEQz4wG30GqXPn7nokufiyhRk='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is
required to enable inline execution.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content Security Policy whitelist hashes doesn't work for inline style attributes but only for inline styles. Maybe in CSP 3.0 will add this functionality

Works for

```
<style>
body { colod: red; }
</style>
```

But DOES NOT work for

```
<body style="color:red;">
</body>
```